# Changing coefficients in second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am considering the following equation:

$$z''(t)+Az'(t)+B=0$$

I need to reduce it to the form

$$u''(t)+u'(t)+1=0$$

by "a linear change of variables z,t"

what do you think it means?
I have tried something like $$u(t)=z\left(\frac{t}{A}\right) + \left(\frac{B}{A^2}-1\right)t$$

but this does not convince me very much!

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: It convinces me.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre What doesn't convince me is that the $t$ in the second equations seems to be a different variable than the $t$ in the first equation...
Also, since the first equation describes the motion of a bouncing ball, it only makes sense for positive $z$...while $u$ could take negative values, as we do not have restrictions on $A$ (I only know it is positive!)

Comment: There are two changes: 1) a change in the variable, which in the real word is equivalent to a change in the time scale 2) a change in the unknown function. If you do not like using the same letter $t$ in both equations, you can call the new time variable $s$ and the new unknown $u(s)$; the relation between both variables is $s=A\,t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following change of variables:

$$ u = \frac{A^2}{B} z $$

and

$$ x = A t $$

thus,

$$ z'' = B u'' $$

and

$$ z' = \frac{B}{A} u' $$

substitute them into your original equation of $ z''(t) + Az'(t) + B = 0 $, to get

$$ u''(x) + u'(x) + 1 = 0. $$

Make sense?

Paul Safier

Further details:

$$ u = \frac{A^2}{B} z $$
gives
$$ du = \frac{A^2}{B} dz $$
and
$$ x = A t $$
gives
$$ dx = A dt $$

From the original equation substitute in the above change of variables:
$$ z'=\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\frac{B}{A^2} du}{\frac{1}{A} dt} = \frac{B}{A} \frac{du}{dx}$$
and
$$ z''= \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dz}{dt}) = A \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{B}{A}\frac{du}{dx})=B\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$$
Plug these terms into the original equation to get:
$$ B\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} +B\frac{du}{dx}+B=0 $$
or
$$ u''(x) + u'(x) + 1 = 0. $$

Cheers,
Paul Safier

Comment: it's clear now, thanks!

Comment: Something wrong in the answer. If we define $u\left(t\right)=\frac{A^2}{B}z\left(x\right)$, then $u'=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{A^2}{B}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{A^3}{B}z'$?

Comment: @ShinKim. Doesn't work like that. I'll edit the solution above to add more steps.